# Zener diode reverse bias I(V) equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-current, voltage, semiconductor-physics, quantum-tunneling

What is the equation for the reverse bias current in terms of voltage applied? And this even be analytically derived? If so, how to derive it.

I can't seem to find good resources on this topic.

Comment: For what it's worth in your searching, "Zener diodes" break down by a combination of avalanche breakdown and the Zener effect.  Also, this is something I'd expect to find in a graduate course in semiconductor devices, so it's a pretty narrowly-focused field of knowledge.

Comment: @EdV i'm pretty sure the second reference is about forward bias only

Comment: @TimWescott the analysis of avalanche brakedown is rather simple.  And even though I still haven't figured out how to relate it to voltege, I think there are a lot of references that can help me with that. Zener effect, however, gives me way more trouble as I immediately gat into a tone of stuff that is not analytically solvable and I cannot find any good reference for this

Comment: @EdV I suppose such an analytical expression is crucial to fully understanding why Zener diode stabilazes the breakdown voltage. And it must be highly important in manufacturing process. So there must be some material on this topic, despite its complexity